# ActiveAdmin Not Working Without Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

So we just went through the process of *removing* Devise and rolled out simple `bcrypt` + `cancancan` auth system.

Now we are also using `ActiveAdmin` as our solution for admin part of the web app, which was tied to `Devise`. Everything is broken on that part of the web app :)

I tried a couple of different things that resolved around adding our own authentication method, but I could not find solution for routes and what else is needed.

We have an `AdminUser` model that's supposed to be admin users. I did "convert" it to use columns normal users use for passwords ( after we made the switch to bcrypt ), but I am completely lost what to do with ActiveAdmin.

Comment: This is a broad question and I posted a broad answer.  If you can be more specific about what exact errors your are encountering, I may be able to provide more accurate help.

Answer (score 3):

There are several items you may need to reconfigure in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`.

You may need to define the authentication method:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb

# == User Authentication
#
# Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
# method in a before filter of all controller actions to
# ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
#
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# within the application controller.
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_active_admin_user!

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def authenticat_active_admin_user!
  # Something that returns true if the current user has access to active admin
end
```

You may also need to set the `current_user` method:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb

# == Current User
#
# Active Admin will associate actions with the current
# user performing them.
#
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# (within the application controller) to return the currently logged in user.
config.current_user_method = :current_user

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def current_user
  # returns the current logged in user.  Devise provides this automatically. You will need to replace that functionality.
end
```

The above are just two things in the Active Admin initializer that affect logging in and authentication.  I would recommend going through the entire and looking at all of the other configs related to user authentication and authorization.  The initializer is well documented with comments and there is plenty of documentation in the Active Admin [homepage](https://activeadmin.info/).  You may find you need to replace some of the other methods active admin is using for authentication and authorization.

Finally, make sure your CanCanCan `Ability` class is able to access the current user.  If your controller is not passing it the correct user, then it will block access.